# How to test if a layer exist in a MapBox GL JS map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I load a GeoJSON layer in a MapBox GL JS map in this way ....

```
    map.addSource("route", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": theCoords
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "route",
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#ff0000",
            "line-width": 4
        }
    });  }
```

... but I need to check if the "route" source and layer exist in my map to remove them before to load the new layer with the same source and name

Does exist in MapBox GL JS any way to test if "route" source and layer exist in my map?

Suggestions / examples / useful links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved in this manner, probably not the best solution but it's working

```
    try {
      map.removeSource("route");
      map.removeLayer("route");
    }
    catch(err) {
//        alert("Error!");
    }
```

Comment: For the purpose on the title of the question (which describes perfectly what I was trying to do, albeit different of the question itself), this would not be a solution..

Answer (score 12):

From:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4466#issuecomment-288177042

> To safely remove a layer that may or may not exist, guard the call to
> removeLayer with getLayer:

```
// Always remove the layer first to avoid an error
if (map.getLayer("route")) {
    map.removeLayer("route");
}

if (map.getSource("route")) {
    map.removeSource("route");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Better way:

```
var mapLayer = map.getLayer('route');

    if(typeof mapLayer !== 'undefined') {
      // Remove map layer & source.
      map.removeLayer('route').removeSource('route');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could consider the following - It won't tell you if there's a previous layer or source, but it will update it to something new once it is moved.  The MapboxGL API has different events to trigger .

Try this if you like:

Suppose the map was initially loaded, and then 
if the user moved or zoomed in on the map,  you could use a

> moveend

event.  Here's an example:

> map.on('style.load', function () {
>
> map.addSource("route", {
>          "type": "geojson",
>          "data": {
>              "type": "Feature",
>              "properties": {},
>              "geometry": theCoords
>          }
>      });
>   map.addLayer({
>           "id": "route",
>           "type": "line",
>           "source": "route",
>           "layout": {
>               "line-join": "round",
>               "line-cap": "round"
>           },
>           "paint": {
>               "line-color": "#ff0000",
>               "line-width": 4
>           }
>       });  }
>
> map.on('**moveend**', function () {

where data would be from an ajax call to your geojson source:
*ulrlz ='https:....jsonData.json'*

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
 url: urlz ,
async: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) 
{
  map.getSource('route').setData(data); //SET THE DATA AGAIN FROM AJAX CALL
     },
error: function (e) {
    alert('error');
    console.log(e);     
}
});
```

Once the call is made when you move or zoom, the source is updated and should redraw what you need.

If you like I could post a working example if you would want to follow this route.